# How do i use a class in another class?

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers

Hi i want to use the foliwng clase Date

```cpp
class Date{
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    Date();
    bool isMonthValid(const int &month);
    bool isDayValid(const int &day);
public:

    Date(const int &day,const  int &month,const  int &year);
    void setDate();
    void endDate();
    void beginDate();
    const int getDay() const;
    const int getMonth() const;
    const int getYear() const;

};
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <headers/domain/model/Data.h>

using namespace std;

Date::Date(const int &day, const int &month, const int &year){

 if(!this->isDayValid(day))
     throw invalid_argument("Invalid value for day.");
 if(!this->isMonthValid(month))
     throw invalid_argument("Invalid value for month.");

 this->day=day;
this->year=year;
this->month=month;
}

bool Date::isDayValid(const int &day) {
    return !(day<31 || day>0);
}

bool Date::isMonthValid(const int &month) {
    return !(month<12 || month>0);
}
const int Date::getDay() const {
    return this->day;
}
const int Date::getYear() const {
    return this->year;
}
const int Date::getMonth() const {
    return this ->day;
}
```

In this one

```cpp
#include "Data.h"
#include "Employee.h"
#include "Badge.h"
class BadgeAssignement{
private:
    BadgeAssignement();
public:
    BadgeAssignement(const int &employeeNumber,const int &day,const int &month,const int &year);
    bool checkEmployee(const int& employeeNumber);
    bool checkDuplicate(const int& employeeNumber);
};

using namespace std;
#include <headers/domain/model/BadgeAssignement.h>
BadgeAssignement::BadgeAssignement(const int &employeeNumber, const int &day, const int &month, const int &year) {
    if(!this->checkEmployee(employeeNumber))
        throw invalid_argument("No employee in the database");


}
bool BadgeAssignement::checkEmployee(const int& employeeNumber){

}
```

How do i use smart pointers in here?Also in the future there wiil be a Badge class where i also want to include in class BadgeAssignement and to check if such badge exists how do i acess such class also with smart_pointers and check if exists?

Here is my part of project that i have to do:

As an HRD staff I want to assign a first/new badge to an existing employee so that (s)he can
start accessing the authorized restricted areas. (Priority: High)
AC033.01 – By default, the starting date of a permanent badge assignment is the current day.
However, the system must accept future dates too.
AC033.02 – Successfully performing a permanent badge assignment implies that current
active (if any) permanent badge assignment record is updated regarding its ending date, which
must be the day before of the new (just created) badge assignment. Example: an employee
has the definitive badge number 423 assigned to him/her since 2018/02/01 with no ending
date. When assigning to him/her another definitive badge (e.g.: with number 1089) starting
on 2022/01/01, the ending date of the initial assignment (badge number 423) must be
updated to 2021/12/31 which is the day before of the new badge assignment.
AC033.03 – To improve usability, the system must support searching employees by name
and/or number.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You just pass and receive `Date` objects as normal. As for the BadgeAssignment class, wouldn't a `std::map<int, BadgeAssignment>` suffice?

Comment: Why do you need smart pointer for `Date` is is small class functionality is primitive there is no reason to keep it on heap, it would be an overkill. Just pass it by value.

Comment: Unrelated: don't pass `int`s by const reference: they are already simple values.

Comment: What i meant to say is can i just include the date header  and use  the month,year,day as  atributes in BadgeAssignment?

Comment: I fail to see the point of the `BadgeAssignment` class. I would expect `Employee` to have a `Badge` member (possibly optional), which has two dates, where the ending date is optional.

Comment: It seems like you are a bit confused about the difference between classes and objects.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks yeah i guess it would made more sense to make it there

Comment: @molbdnilo how do i set a default day of for exemple today?Like the first badge to be assigned today?

Comment: Your default `Date` constructor can figure out what date it is.